# Is it ok to edit an "unclear what you are asking post" inserting a question unaware of thats what OP intended to ask?

Tags: discussion, edits

Motivated by my comment exchange with haccks on this post and the pending edit, I'm not sure about is an edit like this :
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10638386

Ok, if you don't know (even if it is probable, but anyway just a guess) thats what OP intended to ask?
same as asuming what the question may be guided by an given answer (as haccks advises to me)?

Comment: I don't see problem with this edit. Phrase `Can you explain where I am missing and How to avoid this error?` is relatively common form of question about non-working/non-compiled code. Some users omit precise question sentence in such cases, but the editor wants to make question formal (and this looks good for me).

Comment: @Tsyvarev: My point here is, how can you KNOW that OP not was asking about, how to modify the compiler to make his contained code valid. Stupid example but at all... without his statement one can just assume. And I thought thats out of SO's scope. So modyfing OP and risking to alter its meaning wouldn't be valid.

Comment: This question coincides with OP intention in 99.99% cases of non-compiled code. And this question coincides with others' undersanding in 99.99% cases of non-compiled code. Of course, this is not a definite (100%) intention of the OP. But is there *any modification* which is **definitely will coincide with OP intention**? E.g., You edit formatting of the other's code, but what if the author intentionally leave it as unformmated?

Comment: formatting is still diferent from the meaning of a question. But if thats the motivation of why such edit is valid, I'm satisfyed.